# Select2 abort previous ajax request before send a new one

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im using Select2 plugin in my application with Ajax function.

This is my code

```
$(".some-field").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "URL",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        q: params.term, 
        page: params.page
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data, params) {
         //Results 
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
});
```

Before send any Ajax request i need to abort the ones that are currently pending.

In which way should i do it? Thanks in advance for all the help

Comment: to abort ajax requests currently pending there must be a loop somewhere in your code. Please provide more code or be more specific in your question

Comment: The loop is in the select2 plugin. It simply research (and so make a Ajax Request) on typing. I can set a delay for spacing the various requests but i need to be sure that all previous are aborted before send new ones

Comment: isn't `currentRequest` always `null` on `beforeSend`? you need to abort previous requests not current, but to my opinion this must be done internally within select2. Probably old requests are aborted once a new one starts when you type a new key.

Comment: Yes it's true @PeterDarmis, i haven't noticed that but with a deep research in the code i seen that it abort any request before send new ones. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that catch the ajax object, and cancel previous request on sending new request in beforeSend Function.

```
var currentRequest = null;    
$(".some-field").select2({
  currentRequest = ajax: {
    url: "URL",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        q: params.term, 
        page: params.page
      };
    },
    beforeSend : function()    {           
        if(currentRequest != null) {
            currentRequest.abort();
        }
    },
    processResults: function (data, params) {
         //Results 
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I find out (thanks to the advice of @PeterDarmis) that the plugin abort every requests before send new ones. As defined in `AjaxAdapter.prototype.query` method in lines 46-53 of **Select2 [ajax.js](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/master/src/js/select2/data/ajax.js)** .

```
if (this._request != null) {
  // JSONP requests cannot always be aborted
  if ($.isFunction(this._request.abort)) {
    this._request.abort();
  }

  this._request = null;
}
```